# Customized Trait built from multiple inheritance

Tags: python, enthought, traits

I am trying to create a  [custom trait](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/custom.html) which represents a [unipath.Path](https://github.com/mikeorr/unipath#path-and-abstractpath-objects) object.  It seems advantageous to re-use the machinery provided by the  [File](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/trait_types.html#traits.trait_types.File) trait, so my thought was to use multiple inheritance.

```
from unipath import Path
from traits import File

class PathTrait(Path,File):
    pass

class A(HasTraits):
    p = PathTrait()
```

However, when i used this via  `A(p='/tmp/')`, `A.p` does not have any methods associated with the `Path` object, as i would expect. Should i be implementing `get` and `set` methods?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `A(p='/tmp')` should do?

I can tell what you are trying to do but this statement should fail with `TypeError` if your code was correct. Instead of type error, you are replacing the variable P on the `A` object, which was previously an instance of `PathTrait`, with a string.

What you're trying to do is conceptually mixed up. `File` is a class which represents a trait object. Technically python allows you to extend this object, because python has very little type safety, but it doesn't mean your python class will now suddenly act like a trait.

To define custom traits you will need to use tools designed to operate with traits such as the `Trait` constructor.

Comment: i wanted the validation, and traits-ui methods of the `File` trait, but want to use the `__init__` and all other methods of the `Path` object. they seem to  provide features that do not interfere, so i thought the multiple inheritance would work. perhaps your point is that this is a gross simplification. A simple example of how to convert an existing classto a Trait would be sweet.

Comment: Why don't you use a `HasTraits` instance with an `Instance(Path)` object and a `File` property which gets and sets the value on the `Path` object? To me that's the simpler option than defining a customized handler.